# Is there a substantial delay in operationalization when pointing Route 53 purchased DNS to Elastic IP & EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

Having researched a number of the SO QA posts re: pointing a DNS name to an EC2 instance and presently under the impression that I've performed "set up" satisfactorily, yet still encountering DNS lookup failed errors; I wanted to post a question specifically regarding delay.

I have seen discussion that there is a time delay in DNS pointing in correct direction, but such comments have always been in conjunction with outside services (e.g. user wanting to hook up Namecheap-purchased domain to EC2 instance).

My question is: **Do those same time delays apply to a domain purchased within Route 53 and then pointed to an EC2 instance?** I'm currently at ~14 hours post what I perceive is correct set up and want to ensure that I am not sitting idly by if there is an error on my end.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DNS system is a network of DNS servers around the world. When you look up a DNS record on your home machine (say host.domain.com), it usually uses the DNS servers of your internet provider. When present in the cache there, it will (as long as the time-to-live of the record hasn't expired) reply with the cached entry.
When not present in the cache, the DNS servers of your provider will lookup the DNS server for domain.com and query host.domain.com there.

New DNS entries you haven't looked up before should resolve near instantly.
When you lookup a DNS entry you resolved before, and that DNS entry changed on the remote DNS server, you have to wait for the time-to-live to expire before you receive the new DNS entry on your local machine.

In your case, the Route53 records seem to be setup correctly. One last thing you can check is whether the root nameservers for the .org domain point to the R53 records correctly for your domain.
You can check this (on a linux system) using the following commands:
`whois <domain>`
`host -t NS <domain>`

Comment: Thank you for your response.

`whois` response includes a variety of information. Updated date was today (`2016-02-27T04:26:46Z`). Referral URL is a French domain name provider. I do see entries with my name in them, such as `Registrant Name`. 

The `host` method indicated returns `Host j-----------r.org not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)`.

What would I be looking for the those two command line entries? Thanks again.

Comment: In the `whois` output, look for the 'name servers' and check that those point to 'NS' entries for your domain in the R53 console.
Example for stackoverflow.com:  
`Name Server: cf-dns02.stackoverflow.com  
Name Server: cf-dns01.stackoverflow.com`

Comment: In the `host` output, it should return NS records for your domain that point to the same Amazon nameservers. Example for stackoverflow.com:
`stackoverflow.com name server cf-dns02.stackoverflow.com.
stackoverflow.com name server cf-dns01.stackoverflow.com.`

Comment: In case the `whois` output doesn't show the correct nameservers, contact your registrar (where your registered the domain) to make have them update the domain registration to point to the AWS nameservers.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you shared the domain name here, by the way.

Comment: The `whois` information points to different name servers than those showing in your route 53 screenshot. Those servers don't have DNS records for your domain, that why the `host` lookup fails.
Contact your registrar and have the registration for your domain updated to point to the name servers in your R53 screenshot (the servers in the R53 'NS' entry).

Comment: Thanks again, @bert-jan-schrijver. I do see the correct name servers listed under `whois`. Unfortunately, `host` returns `Host jailregister.org not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)`.

Comment: The ones in the question screen shot are from an earlier capture. At present (and since last night) both do align, as the `NS` entries have been: `ns-1770.awsdns-29.co.uk`, `ns-1381.awsdns-44.org`, `ns-468.awsdns-58.com`, `ns-1016.awsdns-63.net`

Comment: OK, in that case it must be something in your R53 configuration. When set up correctly, the name servers should respond to this query instantly:  
`host www.jailregister.org NS-1381.AWSDNS-44.ORG`  
But currently, no result is returned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104739/discussion-between-kuanb-and-bert-jan-schrijver).